# How to check if a mutex is not acquired?

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I want to check if the mutex is free and not acquired.

I tried to use `pthread_mutex_trylock(mutex_object);`

But that return a `0` if mutex is acquired and `-1` for error.

What if the mutex is not acquired? Does it return any value for it?

Answer (score 13):

`pthread_mutex_trylock` does not return "-1 for error". It returns an 'error' code from the possible values in `errno.h`. One of these, `EBUSY`, means that another thread already owns the lock. You should not observe any other error codes from `pthread_mutex_trylock` unless you have serious bugs in your program.

Note that for recursive mutexes, a return value of 0 does not distinguish between the case where the mutex was previously unlocked, and the case where the calling thread already owned it. In any case, if `pthread_mutex_trylock` returns 0, you're responsible for unlocking it via `pthread_mutex_unlock` since you become the owner (or, in the recursive case, your lock count increases by 1) on successful `pthread_mutex_trylock`.

Answer (score 8):

`pthread_mutex_trylock` acquires the mutex for the calling thread or returns `EBUSY` if the mutex is currently locked.  This is the only meaningful way to test if a mutex is locked.  In a multithreaded environment a function that only checks "is someone else holding this mutex" is useless because immediately after the function returns another thread could acquire the mutex.

Answer (score 0):

You usually use pthread_mutex_lock, trylock is a more esoteric non-blocking variant and is used e.g. for avoiding deadlock in priority-inversion scenarios. If you get a 0 return, the mutex was free and is now locked by you.